# node.js @sendgrid/mail Error: Unauthorized

Tags: node.js, angular, http, email, sendgrid

I want to send email from my application (Angular).
I tried to use @sendgrid/mail in my back with node.js, but it's not working.

The error is :

```
(node:18224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unauthorized
    at Request.http [as _callback] (C:\Users\Gauthier\tla\back\node_modules\@sendgrid\client\src\classes\client.js:124:25)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Gauthier\tla\back\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gauthier\tla\back\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gauthier\tla\back\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
(node:18224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:18224) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:18224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unauthorized
    at Request.http [as _callback] (C:\Users\Gauthier\tla\back\node_modules\@sendgrid\client\src\classes\client.js:124:25)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Gauthier\tla\back\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gauthier\tla\back\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gauthier\tla\back\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
(node:18224) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

Maybe some body can help me ?

Please find bellow my app.js

```js
var sendgrid = require('@sendgrid/mail');
app.post('/sendemail', (request, response) => {
    const body = request.body;
    const email = body.email;
    console.log('sendMail');


    SENDGRID_APY_KEY = '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';
    sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_APY_KEY);
    const msg = {
      to: 'ambre.naude@infogene.fr',
      from: 'infogene69@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Votre mot de passe provisoire',
      text: 'Bonjour !',
      html: '<p>Bonjour!</p><p>Voici votre mot de passe provisoire:</p> <p>Cordialement,</p> <p>Infogène Lyon</p>',
    };

    sendgrid.send(msg);
    console.log(msg);

  });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue lies in the below piece

```
SENDGRID_APY_KEY = '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';
    sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_APY_KEY);
```

When you are starting up the server, you need to pass in the sendgrid api key as an env  variable.The above bit of code looks for `SENDGRID_APY_KEY` as an env variable.

To get this to work without passing in env varaiables:

Remove the `process.env` and declare SENDGRID_APY_KEY as a variable.

```
var SENDGRID_APY_KEY = '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';
    sendgrid.setApiKey(SENDGRID_APY_KEY);
```

To pass in the SENDGRID_APY_KEY as an env variable:

```
SENDGRID_APY_KEY='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' node app.js // or however you are starting up the server
```

If you do pass in the key as an env variable, you need to set the sendgrid api from that env variable, like this: `sendgrid.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_APY_KEY)`

Also, you should reset/renew your API key (assuming that the one you posted is your current one)

Comment: If it's heading directly to the spam folder, reach out to sendgrid to see if they can help with that / switch your outbound IP address (assuming you're on a shared IP).

Comment: amazing its working for me. thanks for the solution